# Javascript Library for Editing Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there javascript library or other means of making a webpage that when you double click on a title or something, the text is replaced by a text-entry field with the value of the text that you clicked on?

I am working on a website that has a list of tasks. I want to let the user change the items on the list without having to deal with loading a new page or dealing with a popup or popover. I know I've seen something like this before, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) is what you are looking for. Demo [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might check out AngularJS. It makes this sort of thing almost trivial.

Comment: I might have to check this out. It looks intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

Try CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/) or look into html5 editable - if you want something more basic.

Answer (score 0):

[Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) is by far superior to these examples but it costs money. It lets you upload directly to Amazon S3 which is awesome. I purchased one myself but I can reuse the license again and again.

[KitGUI](http://www.kitgui.com) is also quite good and it takes care of saving to a CDN automatically and works for all technologies and is good for SEO which Redactor only takes care of editing, not displaying after you have edited.